# Multi Party System with n-1 adversaries

Tags: multiparty-computation

Novice here. Is there a MPC function where no information is leaked even if all parties are not trustworthy ?

Comment: If you are a novice, may I suggest you read some books on the subject, which will answer this question and many more?

Comment: The basic answer is yes, by the way, in suitable models and under suitable assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there  are. The search term you are looking for is either "dishonest majority" (which doesn't necessarily mean n-1, but often that is the case) or "full-threshold". The [SPDZ](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/642.pdf) protocol is one that works in the malicious model that would meet your description.